# Edit text doesn't work with the data binding

Tags: android, data-binding

In my layout I removed the top app bar and pasted there an edit text field.
Then I binded that edit text by data binding and set an ObservableField in view model. But it doesn't work... If I remove android:text field with layout and set text from view I can see string in edit text, but if I set binding again there is no visible string. Of course ObservableField in my view model is null. What's going on?
There is any exception?

EDIT:
Ok I resolved my problem:

```
FragmentTodayBinding fragmentTodayBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater,R.layout.fragment_today, container, false);
```

The problem was in container. I changed this word to null and it works fine.

layout:

```
layout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<data>
    <variable
        name="mainViewModel"
        type="com.example.daniellachacz.weatherapp2.viewmodel.MainViewModel" >
    </variable>

    <variable
        name="todayFragmentInterface"
        type="com.example.daniellachacz.weatherapp2.view.TodayFragmentInterface">
    </variable>
</data>

<RelativeLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/blue">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:id="@+id/location_edit"
    android:text="@={mainViewModel.city}"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"/>


<Button
    android:id="@+id/search_button"
    android:onClick="@{(v)-> todayFragmentInterface.onSearchClick(v)}"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_search_white_24dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/condition_text_view"
    android:layout_width="350dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
    android:textSize="27sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/temp_text_view"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/condition_text_view"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/condition_text_view"
    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
    android:textSize="45sp"
    android:gravity="center" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon_image_view"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/condition_text_view"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/condition_text_view" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/wind_text_view"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="37dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/temp_text_view"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:gravity="center"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/humidity_text_view"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="37dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/temp_text_view"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/pressure_text_view"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="37dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/temp_text_view"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="72dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
    android:textSize="16sp" />
```

Viewmodel:

```
public class MainViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

private CurrentWeatherRepository currentWeatherRepository;
public final ObservableField<String> city = new ObservableField<>();


public MainViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
    super(application);
    currentWeatherRepository = new CurrentWeatherRepository(application);
}

public void getCity() {
    currentWeatherRepository.getCurrentWeather(String.valueOf(city.get()), ApiClient.KEY, ApiClient.UNITS);
}
```

Activity:

```
public class TodayFragment extends Fragment {


@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    FragmentTodayBinding fragmentTodayBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater,R.layout.fragment_today, container, false);
    View view = fragmentTodayBinding.getRoot();
    final MainViewModel mainViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainViewModel.class);

    fragmentTodayBinding.locationEdit.setText("X");

    fragmentTodayBinding.setTodayFragmentInterface(new TodayFragmentInterface() {
        @Override
        public void onSearchClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "X", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mainViewModel.getCity();
        }
    });

    mainViewModel.getWeather().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<Weather>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(Weather weather) {
            fragmentTodayBinding.windTextView.setText("Wind: " + String.valueOf(weather.getWind().getSpeed()) + " km/h");
            fragmentTodayBinding.humidityTextView.setText("Humidity: " + weather.getMain().getHumidity() + " %");
            fragmentTodayBinding.pressureTextView.setText("Pressure: " + weather.getMain().getPressure() + " mBar");
            Double temp = weather.getMain().getTemp();
            DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#0.0");
            fragmentTodayBinding.tempTextView.setText(df.format(temp) + " ℃");
            String desc = weather.getDescription();
            String desc2 = Character.toString(desc.charAt(0)).toUpperCase()+desc.substring(1);
            fragmentTodayBinding.conditionTextView.setText(desc2);
            Glide.with(TodayFragment.this).load(weather.getIconUrl()).into(fragmentTodayBinding.iconImageView);
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```